# Erro na view ao usar DisplayFor e foreach

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Fiz esse html dentro do meu cshtml. Fui fazer um foreach e deu erro no foreach e também não reconheceu modelItem. Na pasta Models estão meu edmx, logo T_PDV é uma entidade do BD mapeada nesse edmx.

```
@model SuporteTecnico.Models.T_PDV
@{
     ViewBag.Title = "Formulário";
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Pesquisa</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
     <tr>
          <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RazaoSocial)</th>
          <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CNPJ)</th>
     </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RazaoSocial)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CNPJ)</td>
        </tr>
    }
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Abaixo os erros respectivamente no foreach e no DisplayFor

```
foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'V99SuporteTecnico.Models.T_PDV' because 'V99SuporteTecnico.Models.T_PDV' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'    


The type arguments for method 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor<TModel,TValue>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TValue>>)' 
cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SuporteTecnico.Models.T_PDV` é sua classe.

Para interagir com o `foreach` você precisa usar uma lista, um array...

Seu código deveria ser, por exemplo, assim:

```razor
@model List<SuporteTecnico.Models.T_PDV>
@{
     ViewBag.Title = "Formulário";
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Pesquisa</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
    <tr>
          <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].RazaoSocial)</th>
          <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].CNPJ)</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model){
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RazaoSocial)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CNPJ)</td>
        </tr>
    }
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Então, em sua ***Action***, no ***Controller***, você retornaria uma lista:

```c-sharp
public ActionResult Listar()
{
    var lista = new List<SuporteTecnico.Models.T_PDV>();
    ... // popular a lista
    return view(lista);
}
```

Comment: Eu fiz com IEnumerator<...Models.T_PDV> e deu certo.